# How can I access the file system of a Samsung Galaxy S5 from Terminal (Ubuntu 15.10)?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, mtp

How can I access the file system of a Samsung Galaxy S5 from Terminal (Ubuntu 15.10)?

I want to manipulate the files on my phone from the Terminal of my laptop. However, I'm not sure about how to access them. This for example does not work:

```
cd mtp://[usb:002,013]/Card/SyncTest
```

The phone is connected to the laptop over USB.

Answer (score 0):

MTP is a protocol. Everything you do with `mtp://` share on your Ubuntu involves some software that "talks" MTP.

To make these files available in your directory tree you have to mount the share with a tool that will translate file operations to MTP commands. This is exactly the kind of job [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) is for.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Virtual_file_system) mentions some tools:

> Several tools provide a FUSE based file system for mounting MTP devices within the Unix filesystem hierarchy, making it accessible to any program that operates on files and directories. Examples include `mtpfs`, `jMTPFS`, `go-mtpfs` and `simple-mtpfs`.

Try `apt-cache search mtpfs` in your Ubuntu; it should find few of them. Check `apt-cache show mtp-tools` as well.

A chosen tool will provide you its own command to mount a share. Compare [This ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP), I believe it will be similar in Ubuntu. Unfortunately I have no MTP-capable device to confirm this.

If I were you I would also study these:

- [*How to connect MTP devices via USB?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/146529/693277)
- [*How to connect mtp android device to ubuntu 13.10?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/376815/693277)
- [*Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/87667/693277)

Final hint: whatever FUSE-based solution you choose, unmounting is done by:

```
fusermount -u $mountpoint
```